# Datatables and excelHtml5: We found a problem with some content

Tags: excel, datatables, export

Every file created with Datatables excelHtml5 button export always alerts with below message when opening the file in Excel.

> We found a problem with some content in 'myfile.xlsx'. Do you want us to try to recover as much as we can? If you trust the source of this workbook, click Yes.

I've searched around for several days and tried various things, but I can't figure out what is causing that. Here's my versions of Datatables and Buttons being used:

**Datatables: 1.10.18

Buttons: 1.5.6**

Below is my code. There's some manipulation going on, but I was getting that message before I had that code there.

```
{
          extend: 'excelHtml5',
          autoFilter: false,
          filename: 'myfile',
          sheetName: 'myfile',
          header: false,
          footer: true,
          title: '',
          exportOptions: {
            columns: ':visible',
            format: {
                header: function ( data, column, row )
                {
                    return data.substring(data.indexOf("value")+15,data.indexOf("</option"));
                }
             }
          },
           customizeData: function(data){

                var periods = data.body.length/2;

                var ang_cnt=0, boat_cnt=0, counts=0, hours_cnt=0, shor_pr=0.00, boat_pr=0.00;
                var subtot1 = [], subtot2 = [];
                var TotalPressure = 0.00;

                for(var i=0;i<data.body.length; i++){

                    ang_cnt+=parseInt(data.body[i][1]);
                    boat_cnt+=parseInt(data.body[i][2]);
                    counts+=parseInt(data.body[i][3]);
                    hours_cnt+=parseInt(data.body[i][6]);
                    shor_pr+=parseFloat(data.body[i][7].replace(/[^\d\.]/g,''));
                    boat_pr+=parseFloat(data.body[i][8].replace(/[^\d\.]/g,''));

                    if(i == periods-1){
                        TotalPressure = shor_pr + boat_pr;
                        subtot1 = ['Total',ang_cnt,boat_cnt,counts,' ',' ',hours_cnt,shor_pr.toFixed(2),boat_pr.toFixed(2)];

                        ang_cnt=0;
                        boat_cnt=0;
                        counts=0;
                        hours_cnt=0;
                        shor_pr=0;
                        boat_pr=0;
                    }
                };
                TotalPressure += shor_pr + boat_pr;
                subtot2 = ['Total',ang_cnt,boat_cnt,counts,' ',' ',hours_cnt,shor_pr.toFixed(2),boat_pr.toFixed(2)];
                var totalPresRow = ['Shore-Boat Total Pressure',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',' ',TotalPressure.toFixed(2)];

                var desc = [
                    [' ','Anglers Counted',' ','Number of','Mean # of Anglers',' ','Total Hours','Total Pressure',' '],
                    ['<?=$report_name?>']
                ];
                data.body.unshift(data.header);

                for (var i = 0; i < desc.length; i++) {
                    data.body.unshift(desc[i]);
                };
                var weekendsubhead = ['Weekend Day'];
                var weekdaysubhead = ['Week Day'];
                data.body.splice(3,0,weekendsubhead);
                data.body.splice((periods+4),0,subtot1);
                data.body.splice((periods+5),0,weekdaysubhead);
                data.body.push(subtot2);
                data.body.push(totalPresRow);
            }
      }
```

I'm not sure what I'm looking for to find what's causing the issue. Anyone have any thoughts?

Comment: Can you provide a [mre]? Using your library versions, and your code (except for the `customizeData` function), I do not have the problem you are reporting.

Comment: I'll have to see, the data is dynamic and It's only running locally on my computer at the moment